# extra code in <head> - blank jquery function

Tags: jquery, headers

I recently noticed that in the  of my website (goinspire.com), there are 2 occurrences of the following code:

```
<script>jQuery(function(){});</script>
```

It looks like a script with a blank jquery function.

My questions are:
1) Is this code doing anything
and if not,
2) How do I find out where it's coming from, so I can get rid of it.

I hope I've included all relevant/necessary information. If not, please let me know by commenting below.

This is part of an ongoing project of cleaning up my website and trying to improve page speed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's quite obviously not doing anything, in this instance at least. You will have to search the sources to figure it out most likely.

Comment: Yes, it's doing nothing but it must have been added by some plugin or theme function. WordPress might add some code in it when conditions are met. You will need to find the source by disabling plugin one by one and/or review theme functions.

Comment: Thanks for such quick responses! Are there any hints/tips to see which plugin is causing this, or do I have to go deactivating them one at a time?

Comment: Yes, try doing that. Deactivate plugin one at a time. and if it does not work, deactivate then all and check.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I think it was some old (no longer needed) code in the theme. I got rid of it and the problem is gone. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As per comments: this code is not doing anything.

To find the culprit, first change your theme to a standard one to see if the theme is adding it. If yes, check `header.php` if it is hardcoded there or else `functions.php` for any instances of `add_action('wp_head'...`, where it might be lingering.

If it's not the theme, switch on/off all plugins to see which one is adding it. If you've found the plugin, see if there's an option that might be doing this. In any case, it's not harmful, so if you trust the plugin, just leave it at that.